# How Count Chracters in WordPress Visual Editor

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

For Development purpose, I need to know total number of Characters user has typed.

WordPress uses TinyMCE, Using the logic below, I am able to get character count in console if I edit using Text Editor. But it doesn't work for Visual Editor. WHy ? How to count characters typed in Visual Editor ?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("html").load().on("keyup", function () {
var content = document.getElementById("content").value.length;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While searching on the internet, i come to across same code which counts the number of characters in a visual editor of TinyMCE in WordPress. Link to the original [post](http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/7520) is

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'check_textarea_length' );

function check_textarea_length() {  ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var visual_editor_char_limit = 50;
    var html_editor_char_limit = 50;
    var char_limit_warning="Reduce word count!";

    // jQuery ready fires too early, use window.onload instead

    window.onload = function () {
            // are we using visual editor?
            var visual = (typeof tinyMCE != "undefined") && tinyMCE.activeEditor && !tinyMCE.activeEditor.isHidden()?true:false;

            if(visual){
                    jQuery('.mce-statusbar').append('<span class="word-count-message">'+ char_limit_warning +'</span>');


                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.on('keyup', function(ed,e) {
                            // Strip HTML tags, WordPress shortcodes and white space
                            editor_content = this.getContent().replace(/(<[a-zA-Z\/][^<>]*>|\[([^\]]+)\])|(\s+)/ig,'');


                            // debug:
                            console.log("tinymce editor current #chars: "+editor_content.length);


                            if ( editor_content.length > visual_editor_char_limit ) {


                                    jQuery('#content_ifr').addClass('toomanychars');


                                    // stop any more character input
                                    e.returnValue = false;
                                    e.cancelBubble = true;


                                    // debug:
                                    //console.log(" stop writing! ");


                                    return false;
                            } else {
                                    jQuery('#content_ifr').removeClass('toomanychars');

                            }

                    });
            }

            // do we have html editor?
            if(jQuery("#content").length){

                    jQuery("#content").keyup(function(){

                            // debug:

                             console.log("html editor current #chars : " + jQuery(this).val().length );

                            if(jQuery(this).val().length >  html_editor_char_limit){

                                    jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().substr(0,  html_editor_char_limit));

                                    console.log(char_limit_warning);

                            }

                    });

            }

    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">

            .wp_themeSkin .word-count-message { font-size:1.1em; display:none; float:right; color:#fff; font-weight:bold; margin-top:2px; }
            .wp_themeSkin .toomanychars .mce-statusbar { background:red; }

            .wp_themeSkin .toomanychars .word-count-message { display:block; }

    </style>

    <?php

}
```

Comment: Thanks :D You made my day

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the main purpose of your to count character like that from TinyMCE anyway normal admin script file won't work for this. because you have to need tinymce plugin variable to do something with it.

So first add this code to your functions.php to initialize tinymce plugins filter.

```
function tinymce_init() {
    // Hook to tinymce plugins filter
    add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'tinymce_plugin' );
}
add_filter('init', 'tinymce_init');

function tinymce_plugin($init) {
    // We create a new plugin... linked to a js file.
    // Mine was created from a plugin... but you can change this to link to a file in your plugin
    $init['my_event'] = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js';
    return $init;
}
```

Then add get content length from the `wp_editor` after `keyup` event. Just add on `myscript.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Create 'keyup_event' tinymce plugin
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('my_event', function(editor, url) {
        // Create keyup event
        editor.on('keyup', function(e) {
            var theContent = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
            // alert( theContent.length );
            console.log( theContent.length );
        });
    });
});
```

Hope it make sense to you!

Comment: `code`console.log( theContent.length );`code` This is also counting tags.

Answer (score 0):

I use the solution above, it worked fine during years, but now with Wordpress 6.0.2 i got some problems. When i relaod the edit page with a CTRL+F5, it's ok, all works fine, i reload the page with F5 it's always ok, i change of page, i return to the edit page and nothing, the event init or keyup are not detected, all values are at 0, if i reload with CTRL+F5 it's ok. I don't understand what is the problem.
I use https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/#developers an it uses TinyMCE 4.9.11
I tried this solution too (https://wp-qa.com/keyup-events-in-tinymce-editor-not-working), similar but with a hook added but it's the same problem.

Result on reload with CTRL+F5 :

[image]

But, when it's doesn't work it's like that :

[image]

My code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery('#content').after('<div class="div-caracter-count-message">Nombre de signes (sans espaces) : <span class="caracter-count-message">0</span> / Nombre de signes (avec espaces) : <span class="caracter-count-message-space">0</span></div>');

// Create 'keyup_event' tinymce plugin
tinymce.PluginManager.add('my_event', function(editor, url) {
    // Create keyup event
    editor.on('init keyup', function(e) {
        analyseContent ();
    });
});

// This is needed for running the keyup event in the text (HTML) view of the editor
$('#content').on('keyup', function(e) {
    analyseContent ();
});

// This function allows the script to run from both locations (visual and text)
function analyseContent () {
    var theContent = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent().replace(/(<[a-zA-Z\/][^<>]*>|\[([^\]]+)\])|(\s+)/ig,'');
    var theContentWithSpace = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent().replace(/(<[a-zA-Z\/][^<>]*>|\[([^\]]+)\])/ig,'');
    jQuery('.caracter-count-message').text(theContent.length);
    jQuery('.caracter-count-message-space').text(theContentWithSpace.length);
    //console.log( theContent.length );
    //console.log( tinyMCE.activeEditor.getParam('id') );

    // Selon le nombre de caractères on transforme l'affichage
    if ((theContent.length >= content_max) & (content_max>0)) {
        jQuery('.div-caracter-count-message').css("background-color" ,"#f2dede");
        jQuery('.div-caracter-count-message').css("color", "#a94442");
        jQuery('#save-post').attr("disabled", true);
        jQuery('#publish').attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        jQuery('.div-caracter-count-message').css("background-color" ,"#f7f7f7");
        jQuery('.div-caracter-count-message').css("color", "#444444");
        jQuery('#save-post').attr("disabled", false);
        jQuery('#publish').attr("disabled", false);
    }
}
```

});

Thanks for the help.